# Elasticsearch java HighLevel client update script with params

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to make partial updates by adding an element in my users list:

```
"users" : [
            {
              "password" : "pwd",
              "level" : "admin",
              "user_name" : "XX",
              "last_name" : "YY",
              "first_name" : "ZZ"
            }
]
```

using Kibana I've tried this request:

```
POST my_index/user/1/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.users.add(params.user)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
          "user": {
            "user_name" : "user",
            "first_name" : "XX",
            "last_name" : "XX",
            "level" : "simple",
            "password" : "pwd!#"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine:

```
 "users" : [
                {
                  "password" : "pwd",
                  "level" : "admin",
                  "user_name" : "XX",
                  "last_name" : "YY",
                  "first_name" : "ZZ"
                },
               {
              "password" : "pwd!#",
              "level" : "simple",
              "user_name" : "user",
              "last_name" : "XX",
              "first_name" : "XX"
            }
    ]
```

I want to do it using java client, I've tried this code:

```
XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
            builder.startObject();
            {
                 builder.field("user_name", user.getUserName());
                 builder.field("first_name", user.getFirstName());
                 builder.field("last_name", user.getLastName());
                 builder.field("level", user.getLevel());
                 builder.field("password", user.getPassword());
            }
            builder.endObject();
            params.put("user", Strings.toString(builder));

UpdateByQueryRequest setScript = request.setScript(
                new Script(
                    ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
                    "ctx._source.users.add(params)",                    
                    params)); 
        request.setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(10));

 BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = restHighLevelClient.updateByQuery(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

as result, I had:

```
"users" : [
            {
              "password" : "pwd",
              "level" : "admin",
              "user_name" : "XX",
              "last_name" : "YY",
              "first_name" : "ZZ"
            },
            {
              "user" : """{"user_name":"XX","first_name":"XX","last_name":"XX","level":"XX","password":"XX"}""",
              "ctx" : {
                "_routing" : null,
                "_parent" : null,
                "_index" : "administration",
                "_type" : "environnement",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_version" : 24
              }
            }
          ]
```

so it's not correct, I want to have only user information added to users and I want to do not index ctx informations.

Thanks !

Comment: The first query you made uses the Update API and the one with the REST client uses the Update by query API, so they are different. This is what you're looking for: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update.html#_updates_with_a_script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late but ... there's a typo in your script, you add params instead of params.user.

```
UpdateByQueryRequest setScript = request.setScript(
            new Script(
                ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
                "ctx._source.users.add(params.user)",    <-- here                
                params)); 
    request.setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(10));
```

Anyway, this may not fix it, I've encountered similar problems and found that the easiest solution was to pass each value as a param and create the object once in the script, which would give :

```
parameters.put("user_name", user.getUserName());
parameters.put("first_name", user.getFirstName());
parameters.put("last_name", user.getLastName());
parameters.put("level", user.getLevel());
parameters.put("password", user.getPassword());
request.setScript(new Script(
        ScriptType.INLINE,
        "painless",
        "ctx._source.users.add(params)", 
        parameters));
request.setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(10));
BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = restHighLevelClient.updateByQuery(request,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```